# Timeout error invoking AWS Lambda function from another Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm getting a timeout error when trying to invoke a Lambda function from another Lambda.

I have followed the steps below that I found in another post but still can't get it working. Using this method, should only the public subnet be assigned to each Lambda?

Both Lambdas can successfully run independently and can access the Internet.

What else do I need to configure?

**Current configuration followed:**

Create 2 Subnets, let one be denoted as private and the second public (these terms are explained ahead, keep reading).
Create an Internet Gateway - this is a virtual router that connects a VPC to the internet.
Create a NAT Gateway - pick the public subnet and create a new elastic IP for it (this IP is local to your VPC) - this component will pipe communications to the internet-gateway.
Create 2 Routing Tables - one named public and the second private.

In the public routing table, go to Routes and add a new route:
Destination: 0.0.0.0/0

Target: the ID of the internet-gateway

In the private routing table, go to Routes and add a new route:
Destination: 0.0.0.0/0

Target: the ID of the nat-gateway

A private subnet is a subnet that in its routing table - there is no route to an internet-gateway.

A public subnet is a subnet that in its routing table - there exists a route to an internet-gateway

**Edit:** The two Lambdas are in the same security group- is that correct? I have also tested that the Lambdas can successfully connect to a RDS database in the same VPC.

This is the Python I am using to invoke the second Lambda:

```
try:
    invoke_response = lambda_client.invoke( 
        FunctionName='test_function',
        InvocationType='Event',
        LogType='None',
        Payload=json.dumps(test_payload),
    )
except Exception as invoke_error:
    print(invoke_error)
```

Comment: To create a physical/virtual network, you need a physical connection. You cannot redirect all ports. You can redirect  `port/ports to network` or `network to port/prots`. You've misunderstood the whole thing.

Comment: @dsgdfg - I don't understand your comment. The question explains AWS VPC public and private subnets correctly. Is there something that you see that is wrong?

Comment: How does the first Lambda call the second one? Through an API Gateway? Through AWS-SDK?

Comment: You haven't idea "how to private networks work", got single gateway and you want create a private network, sound like `add a new loopback`.The private networks  are divided into two, `Lo1` and `Br1` .I don't understand which one you want to use, I'm sorry about that. My personal opinion is that Amazon would certainly not allow it, it would be nightmare for other domain names on the same network(so you want use second loopback(`lo1`)).

Comment: @offtheradar *"should only the public subnet be assigned to each Lambda?"*  No, only the **private** subnet should be associated with the Lambda functions.  How did you confirm that the functions can access the Internet?  The fact that you can invoke them does not prove that.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks. I switched the subnets so only the private subnet is assigned to each Lambda now - it didn't solve the timeout though. I confirmed each Lambda can access the Internet using a Python Socket script.

Comment: @dashmug Yeah I'm using boto3. This is the code I am using:

try:
    invoke_response = lambda_client.invoke( 
        FunctionName='test_function',
        InvocationType='Event',
        LogType='None',
        Payload=json.dumps(test_payload),
    )
except Exception as invoke_error:
    print(invoke_error)

Comment: How much time are you allowing before the function times out?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have time out set to 60 seconds

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I just recreated the subnet and route table config and that fixed my issue. Thanks for the tip on assigning the private subnets to the functions!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Lambda function can't invoke another Lambda function in the same VPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62240023/aws-lambda-function-cant-invoke-another-lambda-function-in-the-same-vpc)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues that can arise which will trigger the SDK to [retry the invocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-retries.html), and that may eventually result in a timeout.

VPC configuration is one of these, but another that I ran into was when the Lambda in question has insufficients rights to invoke the other.

Be sure you have an IAM policy like the following in place for the Lambda that needs to invoke the other.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "LambdaInvoke",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "<arn of other Lambda>"
        }
    ]
}
```